# MySql: merge columns fields from mutliple rows into a single one with multiple fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table bundle_group, and its records are like

```
group_id  sku_id
   1        100
   1        101
   2        103
   2        104
```

For each uniq group_id, there are only 2 skus for it.

What I am looking for is a SQL that transforms the records in a form of:

```
 group_id  sku_id1   sku_id2
     1     100     101
     2     103     104
```

I have tried select  `group_id, group_concat(sku_id)..`. This does not satisfied me as all `sku_ids` become a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT
    group_id,
    MIN(sku_id) AS sku_id1,
    MAX(sku_id) AS sku_id2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    group_id;
```

This appears to match the logic in your expected output.  If not, you should state the logic determining which of the two SKU values comes first or second.